# Complex table based content type

Tags: nodes

Hi i have a complex form like this:

[image]

I want to present it as a content type, i don't have any clue how to do it.
i've tried making collections of collection fields and setting its format as table
but it's not what i want. any idea or help i'd be grateful.

Comment: Check once table field module https://www.drupal.org/project/tablefield

Comment: @Smalution Hi, thanks for the answer, i want to be able add rows dynamically and then print the page, can tablefield module do that? (dynamic rows)

Comment: Have you looked at Views module? It has a table formatter.

Comment: @Beebee Hi, thanks for the answer, what i'm really stuck at is that i should do it programmatically or there are modules to do this